# How does scanl in Haskell work on list of Either's - comparison of two cases

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-declaration

I am trying to use the `scanl` function in Haskell. I have narrowed down my problem which can be described in the following two cases, which can be run in the interpreter using just a normal library within Haskell that contains the `scanl` (Note that I am not necessarily interested in the Monadic value here, but just how to use `scanl` to ensure a type consistency):

Why does the following with pre-listed `Right value`s work work:

```
*Defs> scanl (\x acc -> x ++ acc) [] [[(Right 1)], [(Right 2)]]  
[[],[Right 1],[Right 1,Right 2]]
```

when this doesn't work and causes the following error message:

```
*Defs> scanl (\x acc -> [x] ++ acc) [] [(Right 1), (Right 2)]

<interactive>:36:35: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[[a]]'
                  with actual type `Either a0 b0'
   ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have the value and accumulator swapped. Consider the type of `scanl`:

```
ghci> :t scanl
scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
```

The accumulator value is of the type `b`. It comes first.

If you swap the arguments in your second example, it works:

```
ghci> scanl (\acc x -> acc ++ [x]) [] [(Right 1), (Right 2)]
[[],[Right 1],[Right 1,Right 2]]
```

You can also swap the argument of the first example, and that, too, works:

```
ghci> scanl (\acc x -> acc ++ x) [] [[(Right 1)], [(Right 2)]]
[[],[Right 1],[Right 1,Right 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you here aim to do already exists, this is [**`inits :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits), it produces all prefixes. You use a list of lists, but that can be processed by concatenating instead of pretending.

Each time constructing a new list that appends at the right end will however require *(n<sup>2</sup>)* which makes sense, since the total construction indeed *(n<sup>2</sup>)*. But it is possible that we want only to generate the last lists for example.

Therefore it might be better to work with a *difference list*, which allows to append one element in *(1)* and thus will eventually take only *(n<sup>2</sup>)* time if we wish to only construct one of the last items for example:

```
dapp :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
dapp [] f = f
dapp (x : xs) f = dapp xs (f . (x :))

dground :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a]
dground = ($ [])
```

so we can construct the function as:

```
ourInits :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
ourInits = map dground . scanl (flip dapp) id
```